# Simple linux script help

Tags: linux, shell

I have a text file with the following structure:

```
text1;text2;text3;text4
...
```

I need to write a script that gets 2 arguments: the column we want to search in and the content we want to find.

So the script should output only the **lines** (**WHOLE LINES!**) that match content(arg2) found in column x(arg1).

I tried with egrep and sed, but I'm not experienced enough to finish it. I would appreciate some guidance...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given your added information of needing to output the entire line, `awk` is easiest:

```
awk -F';' -v col=$col -v pat="$val" '$col ~ pat' $input
```

Explaining the above, the `-v` options set `awk` variables without needing to worry about quoting issues in the body of the `awk` script.  Pre-POSIX versions of `awk` won't understand the `-v` option, but will recognize the variable assignment without it.  The `-F` option sets the field separator.  In the body, we are using a pattern with the default action (which is `print`); the pattern uses the variables we set with `-v` for both the column (`$` there is `awk`'s "field index" operator, not a shell variable) and the pattern (and `pat` can indeed hold an `awk`-style regex).

Comment: `mawk` is one variant of `awk`, yes.  It should be compatible with what I wrote; some `awk`s won't understand `-v`, but you can just list the variable settings without the `-v` prefix in that case (pre-POSIX syntax for command line variable settings).

Comment: To use shell variable (by value) in awk I often do: awk -F';' '$'$COL' ~ '$PAT'' $OUTPUT . Note, that $COL is a shell variable, which is seen by awk as value (of that variable). This method is less readable but more universal across many awk implementations.

Answer (score 1):

```
cat text_file.txt| cut -d';' column_num | grep pattern
```

It prints only the column that is matched and not the entire line. let me think if there is a simple solution for that.

Comment: But i need to output the whole line, not just the found column.

Answer (score 1):

Python

```
 #!/usr/bin/env python
 import sys
 column = 1 # the column to search
 value = "the data you're looking for"
 with open("your file","r") as source:
    for line in source:
        fields = line.strip().split(';')
        if fields[column] == value:
             print line
```

Answer (score 0):

There's also a solution with `egrep`. It's not a very beautiful one but it works:

```
egrep "^([^;]+;){`expr $col - 1`}$value;([^;]+;){`expr 3 - $col`}([^;]+){`expr 4 - $col`}$" filename
```

or even shorter:

```
egrep "^([^;]+;){`expr $col - 1`}$value(;|$)" filename
```

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -B1 -i "string from previous line" |grep -iv 'check string from previous line' |awk -F" " '{print $1}'
```

This will print your line.